# MySQL formula to determine number of maximum concurrent events

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to think of a way to take two fields entries in a MySQL table (One being a timestamp e.g., '2013-07-31 11:59:46' and the other being a duration of time in seconds e.g., '55'  and find all the records that overlap each other and how many of them are overlapped during that period of time.  I already have a headache but I'm sure it can be done somehow? What would be a good way to get the return value?

So for instance,  say I have a total of 5 entries from Jan 1st

```
2013-01-01 09:00:00 | 30     (an event that started at 9:00am and lasted 30 seconds)
2013-01-01 09:02:00 | 360    (an event that started at 9:02am and lasted 6 minutes)
2013-01-01 09:03:00 | 600    (an event that started at 9:03am and lasted 10 minutes)
2013-01-01 09:11:00 | 10    (an event that started at 9:11am and lasted 10 seconds)
2013-01-01 09:12:00 | 30    (an event that started at 9:12am and lasted 30 seconds)
```

Running against these entries I'd get a return value of "2" since that is the maximum amount of concurrent events. (Events #2 & #3 overlap. Then, Event #2 ends before Event #3 and #4 start, which in turn, overlap. This does not change our return value as there are still only two concurrent events at any given time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,dt DATETIME NOT NULL
 ,duration INT NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table (dt,duration) VALUES
 ('2013-01-01 09:00:00',30),
 ('2013-01-01 09:02:00',360),
 ('2013-01-01 09:03:00',600),
 ('2013-01-01 09:11:00',10),
 ('2013-01-01 09:12:00',30);


  SELECT *
    FROM my_table x
    JOIN my_table y
      ON y.id <> x.id
     AND y.dt < (x.dt + INTERVAL x.duration SECOND)
     AND (y.dt + INTERVAL y.duration SECOND) > x.dt;
 +----+---------------------+----------+----+---------------------+----------+
 | id | dt                  | duration | id | dt                  | duration |
 +----+---------------------+----------+----+---------------------+----------+
 |  3 | 2013-01-01 09:03:00 |      600 |  2 | 2013-01-01 09:02:00 |      360 |
 |  2 | 2013-01-01 09:02:00 |      360 |  3 | 2013-01-01 09:03:00 |      600 |
 |  4 | 2013-01-01 09:11:00 |       10 |  3 | 2013-01-01 09:03:00 |      600 |
 |  5 | 2013-01-01 09:12:00 |       30 |  3 | 2013-01-01 09:03:00 |      600 |
 |  3 | 2013-01-01 09:03:00 |      600 |  4 | 2013-01-01 09:11:00 |       10 |
 |  3 | 2013-01-01 09:03:00 |      600 |  5 | 2013-01-01 09:12:00 |       30 |
 +----+---------------------+----------+----+---------------------+----------+

 or, if you prefer...

  SELECT *
    FROM my_table x
    JOIN my_table y
      ON y.id < x.id
     AND y.dt < (x.dt + INTERVAL x.duration SECOND)
     AND (y.dt + INTERVAL y.duration SECOND) > x.dt;
 +----+---------------------+----------+----+---------------------+----------+
 | id | dt                  | duration | id | dt                  | duration |
 +----+---------------------+----------+----+---------------------+----------+
 |  3 | 2013-01-01 09:03:00 |      600 |  2 | 2013-01-01 09:02:00 |      360 |
 |  4 | 2013-01-01 09:11:00 |       10 |  3 | 2013-01-01 09:03:00 |      600 |
 |  5 | 2013-01-01 09:12:00 |       30 |  3 | 2013-01-01 09:03:00 |      600 |
 +----+---------------------+----------+----+---------------------+----------+
```

For 'event 1', 2 things are overlapping (item 2 & item 3). 
For 'event 2', 2 things are overlapping (item 3 & item 4). 
For 'event 3', 2 things are overlapping (item 3 & item 5).

```
   9.00  9.01  9.02  9.03  9.04  9.05  9.06  9.07  9.08  9.09  9.10  9.11  9.12  9.13
 1   |-|
 2               |-----------------------------------|
 3                     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
 4                                                                     |-|
 5                                                                           |-|
```

If you like, we can say that:

```
nothing overlaps item 1
1 thing overlaps item 2 (item 3), 
3 things overlap item 3 (items 2, 4, & 5), and
1 thing (item 3) overlaps each of items 4 & 5!


 SELECT x.id
      , COUNT(y.id) overlaps
    FROM my_table x
    LEFT
    JOIN my_table y
      ON y.id <> x.id
     AND y.dt < (x.dt + INTERVAL x.duration SECOND)
     AND (y.dt + INTERVAL y.duration SECOND) > x.dt
   GROUP
      By x.id;

 +----+----------+
 | id | overlaps |
 +----+----------+
 |  1 |        0 |
 |  2 |        1 |
 |  3 |        3 |
 |  4 |        1 |
 |  5 |        1 |
 +----+----------+
```

A simple ORDER BY and LIMIT will you get you the highest of these.

I won't accept payment here - but some points would be nice!

Comment: I guess he's asking for the `MAX(COUNT(*))`.

Comment: Wow that was quick! Hi Strawberry, so in the second formula (that seems to filter out the non-overlapping records) the second "id" column groups the overlapping calls into a number, then I just use some type of count or group to find the maximum number of concurrent events?

Comment: Both queries filter out 'non-overlapping' records! 2 overlaps with 3 and 3 overlaps with 2, 4, & 5. The difference is that the second query shows each overlap only once. This may or may not be desirable!

Comment: ohh Ok, now I see that the "9:00:00" did get filtered out.   So to find the maximum number of simultaneous that happened at one time, what would I need to add? (in this case would be 3 unless I'm totally brain dead today, for 09:03:00, 09:11:00, and 09:12:00 all were happening at once?)

Comment: Draw it out on a piece of paper if you like. There are only ever 2 concurrent events. Item 3 overlaps almost all of item 2, then runs on its own for a bit, then overlaps all of item 4, and then overlaps all of item 5. No other event overlaps any other.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and patience :)   I think I overcomplicated everything, so there's 2 concurrent events, but I wak looking for the amount of items in the events.  So for concurrent event #1, two actual events are overlapping, then for Event #2, 3 items are overlapping.  I'm looking for a formula that would return "3" for the max number of items overlapping in any one event.  Is there anyway I can paypal you or something?  I feel that you should be compensated for my low IQ lol